# How to add and execute a binary in Azure Functions?

Tags: python, linux, azure, azure-functions

I need to run a linux binary (`ffmpeg` for the sake of this example) from within an Azure function that runs python/linux.

I haven't found how to package it nor how to execute it.

[Some of the python docs on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python) show that there can be a `bin/` root folder as part of function's package. Putting the file there and then calling `subprocess.run()` on it fails. It apparently cannot find the executable.

I have tried moving the file to the root directory, or trying to find it with a full path (I've tried `/home/site/www` and variations of it). Still no luck.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I followed the offical tutorial [`Create your first Python function in Azure (preview)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python) to create a `HttpTrigger` Function for Python, and tried different ways to make `ffmpeg` works in Azure Functions, then it works for me.

Here is my steps to do that above, as below, hope it helps.

1. Follow the offical tutorial of Azure Funtions for Python to install `Azure Functions Core Tools` on my local Windows machine to create a project named `MyFunctionProj` and a function named `HttpTrigger`.
2. Before to upload `ffmpeg` with deployment, I check the OS platform architecture of my instance of Azure Functions on Azure via change the offical sample code with the code below.

   ```
   # add these codes
   import platform, os
   .....

   def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       if name:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! {platform.architecture()}")
   ```

   Its result is `Hello peter-pan! ('64bit', '')` in broswer.
3. Then I put the `ffmpeg` AMD64 static binary file downloaded from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ into my `MyFunctionProj` and change my code below to check the file path, and to command `func azure functionapp publish <my app name>` to publish to Azure.

   ```
   def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       if name:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! {platform.architecture()} {os.listdir()} {os.listdir('HttpTrigger')}")
   ```

   Its result is `Hello peter-pan! ('64bit', '') ['in.mp4', 'ffmpeg', 'host.json', 'requirements.txt', 'ffmpeg.exe', '.python_packages', 'HttpTrigger']  ['in.mp4', '__pycache__', 'sample.dat', 'host.json', 'function.json', '__init__.py']` in broswer as same as these in my `MyFunctionProj`
4. I found everything in `MyFunctionProj` folder will be uploaded to Azure and call `os.listdir()` to show the file list of `MyFunctionProj`, so the current path in Python is the same as `MyFunctionProje` locally. Then I tried to invoke `ffmpeg` in my local Windows environment via the code below.

   ```
   def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       if name:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! {platform.architecture()} {os.listdir()} {os.listdir('HttpTrigger')} {os.path.exists('in.mp4')} {os.popen('ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 out.mp4').read()} {os.path.exists('out.mp4')} {os.popen('del out.mp4').read()}")
   ```

   It works to output the file `out.mp4` via command `ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 out.mp4`, then considering for reproduce it to command `del out.mp4`.
5. Try to make it works for Linux enviroment on Azure Function, I change the commands with `./ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mp4` and `rm out.mp4`. But it didn't work on Azure Function. It may be caused by missing the execute permission of `ffmpeg` linux binary file while uploading from Windows. So I checked my guess via command `ls -l ffmpeg` and `chmod u+x ffmpeg` before invoke it.

   ```
   def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       if name:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! {platform.architecture()} {os.listdir()}  {os.listdir('HttpTrigger')} {os.popen('ls -l ffmpeg').read()} {os.popen('chmod u+x ffmpeg').read()} {os.popen('ls -l ffmpeg').read()} {os.path.exists('in.mp4')} {os.popen('./ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mp4').read()} {os.path.exists('out.mp4')} {os.popen('rm out.mp4').read()}")
   ```

   It works now, the result is like below I formated it pretty.

   ```
   Hello peter-pan! // Offical sample output
   ('64bit', '') // the Linux platform architecture of Azure Functions for Python 
   ['in.mp4', 'ffmpeg', 'host.json', 'requirements.txt', 'ffmpeg.exe', '.python_packages', 'HttpTrigger']  // file list of MyFunctionProj
   ['in.mp4', '__pycache__', 'sample.dat', 'host.json', 'function.json', '__init__.py'] // file list of HttpTrigger
   -r--r--r-- 1 root root 69563752 Mar 13  2019 ffmpeg // before chmod u+x
   -rwxr--r-- 1 root root 69563752 Mar 13  2019 ffmpeg // after chmod u+x
   True  // in.mp4 exists
   True // out.mp4 exists before delete it using `rm`
   ```

Note: I think the issue of execute permission of `ffmpeg` will be happened when you were developing in Linux. And the `in.mp4` file comes from https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/in.mp4. I had tried to use `ffmpeg-python` package to realize your need, but it seems not to work on local and Azure.

Answer (score 2):

You can run commands such as `apt-get install ffmpeg` from the Kudu console on `https://<YOUR-APP>.scm.azurewebsites.net`.

But the environment will be reset if you deploy or scale your app. Another solution would be to use a docker deployment so you can specify which binaries you want to add on the server.